# Get access token for FB with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get a FB access token to get events for a user. For the same i could not find a solution using REST. looks like all FB use is Graph API.

The tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ was able to give me a token but it is something short lived and expires in few hours. I need something which will stay longer and with minimal user interaction. Zero interaction if required (may be pick up FB session details from the cookies and pass on)

Things i may want to avoid:
1. FB PHP SDK 
2. FB app permission dialog box, as the use case would be a chrome extension and i am not sure if FB can have dialog box invoked from Chrome extns.

I am following : https://www.sammyk.me/access-token-handling-best-practices-in-facebook-php-sdk-v4 but as i mentioned i don't want to use SDK and this is what this is using.

Comment: If you don’t want to use any SDK, then you will have to implement the manual login flow yourself. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.4

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

`graph.facebook.com/me/events?method=get&access_token={usertoken}`

If you are looking for access tokens that accept that permission, then you can use HTC app permission.

> https://www.facebook.com/v1.0/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_actions.books%2Cuser_actions.music%2Cuser_actions.news%2Cuser_actions.video%2Cuser_activities%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_education_history%2Cuser_events%2Cuser_games_activity%2Cuser_groups%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_interests%2Cuser_likes%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_notes%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_questions%2Cuser_relationship_details%2Cuser_relationships%2Cuser_religion_politics%2Cuser_status%2Cuser_subscriptions%2Cuser_videos%2Cuser_website%2Cuser_work_history%2Cfriends_about_me%2Cfriends_actions.books%2Cfriends_actions.music%2Cfriends_actions.news%2Cfriends_actions.video%2Cfriends_activities%2Cfriends_birthday%2Cfriends_education_history%2Cfriends_events%2Cfriends_games_activity%2Cfriends_groups%2Cfriends_hometown%2Cfriends_interests%2Cfriends_likes%2Cfriends_location%2Cfriends_notes%2Cfriends_photos%2Cfriends_questions%2Cfriends_relationship_details%2Cfriends_relationships%2Cfriends_religion_politics%2Cfriends_status%2Cfriends_subscriptions%2Cfriends_videos%2Cfriends_website%2Cfriends_work_history%2Cads_management%2Ccreate_event%2Ccreate_note%2Cexport_stream%2Cfriends_online_presence%2Cmanage_friendlists%2Cmanage_notifications%2Cmanage_pages%2Cphoto_upload%2Cpublish_stream%2Cread_friendlists%2Cread_insights%2Cread_mailbox%2Cread_page_mailboxes%2Cread_requests%2Cread_stream%2Crsvp_event%2Cshare_item%2Csms%2Cstatus_update%2Cuser_online_presence%2Cvideo_upload%2Cxmpp_login&response_type=token&client_id=41158896424